# Angular 2 project developed using cli publish as npm package

Tags: angular, npm, angular2-routing, angular-cli, node-modules

We are planning to develop a large application using angular 2. So we have one parent angular 2 application, which have 3 sub child applications which do not have any relations to each other. So we developed this 3 sub child applications as 3 different angular 2 applications and these applications have its own routing. Now i want to publish this project into npm, so that i can fetch these projects in parent application. Currently i am stuck at publishing project to npm. Can any one provide me a proper tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Angular-cli projects are NPM packages since they use a `package.json` please refer to NPM's [tutorial on publishing packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages)

Also, please read [this section](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) on `.npmignore` you'll need it to publish a clean package.

After publishing, install the published packages as you would any npm package and import the modules, components, services ...etc from the correct location under `node_modules/<newly published package>/path/to/tsFile`

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: what about the style.css and asset folder?